# SPARQL: Get all entities from a P279+ query

Tags: sparql, wikidata

Example: `Q11862829` is subclass of `Q1047113`, which is subclass of `Q9081`. Can I build a query that returns all entities of which `Q11862829` is subclass of between it and `Q9081`?
`wd:Q11862829 wdt:P279+ wd:Q9081` is "close to what I want.

Comment: Have you tried this:
SELECT ?entity WHERE {?entity wdt:P31 ?class . wd:Q11862829 wdt:P279* ?class . ?class wdt:P279* wd:Q9081}

Comment: Thanks, that was really easy but I just can't think straight these days. What I really needed was `SELECT ?class
WHERE
{
  wd:Q9081 wdt:P279+ ?class .
  ?class wdt:P279+ wd:Q2200417
}`. Feel free to create an answer.